# logout without verifying email Laravel / exclude a route from AUTH routes Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, email-verification, laravel-authentication

I'm only posting this to make it easy for fellow devs to find the answer more quickly because I  couldn't find it on stack overflow so  I just figured it out for myself.

basically, I added email verification to my routes but when I try to logout it  kept redirecting me to the verification page which is normal because I did `Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);` but when I tried to look for a way to exclude logout route I found this answer

```
Route::post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');



Route::group(['verify' => true], function () {


// User Password Reset Routes
Route::get('password/reset', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('password.request');
//..... and all the other auth routes

});
```

but it didn't work along with other answers

Answer (score 0):

this worked just fine

```
Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);
/// excluded routes  
Route::get('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');
```